# VBA Not Reading Cell Value Into Text Box on Initialize

Tags: excel, vba

```
Private Sub UserFormStart_initialize()

TextBoxTaxYear.Value = Sheet2.Range("E5").Value

TextBoxFname.Value = Sheet2.Range("E6").Value

TextBoxSname.Value = Sheet2.Range("E7").Value

TextBoxDOB.Value = Sheet2.Range("E8").Value

TextBoxPPSN.Value = Sheet2.Range("E9").Value

TextBoxNation.Value = Sheet2.Range("E10").Value

TextBoxDoorHouse.Value = Sheet2.Range("E11").Value

TextBoxStreet.Value = Sheet2.Range("E12").Value

TextBoxCity.Value = Sheet2.Range("E13").Value

TextBoxCounty.Value = Sheet2.Range("E14").Value

TextBoxEir.Value = Sheet2.Range("E15").Value

TextBoxCountry.Value = Sheet2.Range("E16").Value

TextBoxEMail.Value = Sheet2.Range("E17").Value


End Sub
```

Comment: Hi and welcome. Can you provide a bit more context? What is your question? which of the cell values is not transfered to your TextBox? All, only a few? Is the method at all called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't replace UserForm with the form name, it's *always* Private Sub UserForm_Initialize.

```
Private Sub UserForm_initialize()

    TextBoxTaxYear.Value = Sheet2.Range("E5").Value

    TextBoxFname.Value = Sheet2.Range("E6").Value

    TextBoxSname.Value = Sheet2.Range("E7").Value

    TextBoxDOB.Value = Sheet2.Range("E8").Value

    TextBoxPPSN.Value = Sheet2.Range("E9").Value

    TextBoxNation.Value = Sheet2.Range("E10").Value

    TextBoxDoorHouse.Value = Sheet2.Range("E11").Value

    TextBoxStreet.Value = Sheet2.Range("E12").Value

    TextBoxCity.Value = Sheet2.Range("E13").Value

    TextBoxCounty.Value = Sheet2.Range("E14").Value

    TextBoxEir.Value = Sheet2.Range("E15").Value

    TextBoxCountry.Value = Sheet2.Range("E16").Value

    TextBoxEMail.Value = Sheet2.Range("E17").Value

End Sub
```